# Can I ask for a translation of a routine from one programming language to another?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Is it acceptable to ask if someone can write a routine in programming language A if I show exactly what I want in programming language B? For example, I am considering asking if someone can write something in Vimscript if I show in JavaScript exactly what I want. Also, I intend to ask about a single, rather restricted function, not an entire program.

On the negative side, my question does *not* show that I've made any effort at all to solve the most direct problem (i.e. write the Vimscript) on my own.

On the positive side, my question *does* show that I *have* made an effort to work through the *logic* of what I'm looking for.

I know that Stack Exchange wants to avoid questions that ask "Can anyone do my work for me?". On the other hand, the question above *does* show background understanding, asks a specific question, and provides appropriate context. But is that enough? And if it isn't, is there another place on Stack Overflow where I *could* legitimately ask this sort of question.

[This other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68322/350387) doesn't specifically ask the same question I'm asking (it focuses on what tags to use for such questions), but it shows that asking questions like this one at least *does* happen. However, acknowledging that it does happen doesn't necessarily mean that it's appropriate which is what I'm asking here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that's not appropriate. It's no different than just posting a detailed requirements document and asking people to implement it for you.

Translate the code yourself.  If you run into a specific problem with translating a specific section, then it may be appropriate to as a very specific question about how to do a very specific thing in the target language, assuming you do the appropriate research on how to resolve that issue before asking the question.  Make sure to describe not just what you need, but why you're unable to solve that problem, what you had done, why it didn't work, etc.